# definition of tensors and its connection to examples of tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Tensors are often introduced using tensor products or multilinear maps. I think I understand how they hang together. The examples given (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) are then a bit different, and I don't understand the connection. Let me illustrate. Wikipedia introduces tensors as multilinear maps

$$
T:V^{*}\times\ldots\times{}V^{*}\times{}V\times\ldots\times{}V\rightarrow{}R
$$

where $V$ is a vector space, $R$ is usually the real numbers, and $V^{*}$ is the dual space with respect to $V$. $T$ can be identified with the element of a tensor product

$$
T\in{}V\otimes\ldots\otimes{}V\otimes{}V^{*}\otimes\ldots\otimes{}V^{*}
$$

using the components of the tensor and a basis for $V$.

Then an example is given, for example a linear transformation. These examples are almost always maps from $V^{p}$ to $V^{q}$, where $p$ is the number of covariant indices and $q$ is the number of contravariant indices, so

$$
T:V\times\ldots\times{}V\rightarrow{}V\times\ldots\times{}V
$$

I don't quite understand how such maps are identified with tensors as they have been defined. For a linear transformation, for example,

$$
L:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}
$$

with $L(v)=Gv=w$, where $G$ is an $n\times{}n$ (in this case, $2\times{}2$) matrix. The tensor, however, is a map

$$
L':\mathbb{R}^{2*}\times\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$

identified with the element $L'\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\otimes\mathbb{R}^{2*}$ such that

$$
L'=L_i{}^j(e^{i}\otimes{}e_{j})
$$

(Einstein summation). How are $L_i{}^j$ and $G_{ij}$ related? I feel like the answer should be obvious, but it isn't to me. And what is $L'(\alpha,v)=t$ in the real numbers for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{2*}$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ if I understand $L'$ to be the multilinear map corresponding to the linear transformation $L$ using the matrix $G$, so $L(v)=Gv$?

Comment: The answer is indeed obvious for linear transformations, but I still don't quite understand how this works. Let's say $x=1$

Comment: Oops, things timed out on me. I just read Jeffrey M. Lee on this in his book Manifolds and Differential Geometry, pages 311f, but I am none the wiser, and he will only talk about linear transformations and their relationship to tensors as they are defined, but what about a tensor such as T(2,3)(alpha,beta,v1,v2,v3)=t, which is supposed to correspond to a multilinear map L(v1,v2,v3)=(w1,w2)?

Comment: So, what can be said about a tensor T(1,1) for a vector space with dimension n is that according to the tensor product definition, T(1,1)=sum \tau ij e(i) \otimes E(j) (the e(i)'s are the basis vectors of V and the E(j)'s are the basis vectors of the dual space V*). Then, according to the multilinear map definition, T(1,1)(\alpha,v)=\sum \tau ij \alpha(j)(e(j)) E(i)(v(i)) (where the alpha(j) and v(i) are the coordinates of \alpha and v given the bases E(j) and e(i)).

Comment: According to the way the examples are given, T(1,1)(v)=\Tau v, where \Tau is the linear transformation corresponding to the matrix with the entries \tau ij. This explains things for the case T(1,1), but what about more general T(r,s) tensors?